# javascript regex with variables

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I define regex variables for example in case of converting html link tag to angular link tag:

from

```
<a href="/myapp/home">Home</a>
<a href="/myapp/about">About</a>
... many others can include more a, html, divs, tables etc
```

to

```
<a [routerLink]="['/home']">Home</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/about']">About</a>
... without change
```

It seems as easy task but the most important is that the names "home" "about" are dynamic so I need to define them as anything variable, something like:

```
<a{ANYTHING as $1}href="/myapp/{ANYTHING as $2}"
```

to

```
<a $1 [routerLink]="['$2']"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really not sure regex is the best approach here,  but here is an example:

```js
str = '<a some content 1 href="/myapp/home" some other content 2>Home</a>'
regex = /<a(.*)href="\/myapp(\/[^"]*)"(.*)>(.*)<\/a>/
if (regex.test(str)) {
  t = regex.exec(str)
  new_str = '<a' + t[1] + '[routerLink]=\"[\''+t[2] +'\']\"'+t[3]+'>'+t[4]+'</a>'
  console.log(str)
  console.log(new_str)
}
```

Comment: ye, nice thx. Any advices about what would be better than regex?

Comment: usually when dealing with xml/html we use dom-parsing (and not regex)

Comment: In my case I can use only javascript solution, maybe thats main problem here